# cannot figure out how to manipulate mysql query according sessions

Tags: jquery, mysql

> im posting category id via ajax to below page

```
if(isset($_POST['category'])){
        $cat=$_POST['category'];
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['k'.$cat])){
            unset($_SESSION['k'.$cat]);
        }else {
            $_SESSION['k'.$cat]= "category_code='".$cat."' ";
            }
        };
```

> Now i have sessions set for each posted value and want to manipulate query according to sessions

for each session i set i want my query include category code inside query

```
$products=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_code='$_SESSION[$cat1]' || category_code='$_SESSION[$cat4]'...etc ")
```

Comment: category_code='".$_SESSION[$cat1]."' || category_code='".$_SESSION[$cat4]."' try this

Answer (score 0):

One big problem I see is that you're adding `category_code=` to the beginning of the value you stored in the `$_SESSION` array. So when you set up your SQL query, it's going to look like this: `...WHERE category_code='category_code=...`.

You could also try moving the variable outside the quotes: `"...WHERE " . $_SESSION[$cat1] . " OR " . $_SESSION[$cat4]`.

Note: you really ought to be using the `mysqli` object or `PDO`, as in `$products = $mysqli->query(...);`